# Can you use Botkit and botframework on azure webchat and skype?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, botkit, microsoft-skype-bot

I've set up a starterkit on studio.botkit.ai for Microsoft Teams. The bot is hosted on glitch. In Azure bot registration I've included the endpoint provided by glitch. Ive also added my id and password from azure bot registration to my bot.

When I try and test out the bot in azure web chat I sends an error that reads

**"There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound"**

It this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the messaging endpoint URL configured in Azure matches your Glitch url for Botkit, which will include "/receive/teams"